# How do i prevent duplicate records in my database while updating records?

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-update, unique

in my mysql table I made look like this one

```
ControlNum|Title  |NumOfEpis|Description|
001       |naruto |500      |some text  |
002       |conan  |700      |some text  |
```

now I made a user control in C# where in the user is allowed to update all columns except the primary"ControlNum". so assuming each column has its own textboxes in that said user control so in order to avoid duplication in the title column like for example if the user edit the row 2 title and put it "naruto" also it would be duplicated..so I create this method called checkData();

```
void checkData()
    {
        SuspendLayout();
        try
        {
            MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(myConnection);
            conn.Open();
            MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM maindatabase.animelist where TitleAnime=?Title;", conn);
            //command.Parameters.AddWithValue("?CN", int.Parse(a.ToString()));
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("?Title", textBox3.Text);
            MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

            int ctr = 0;
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                ctr++;

            }
            if (ctr == 1)
            {
                my = Form.ActiveForm as MyList;
                my.msg = new Message_Box();
                my.msg.Descrip.Text = "Record is already in the Database";
                my.msg.Title.Text = "Duplicate Record";
                my.msg.ShowDialog();
            }
            else
            {

                updateData();
            }


            conn.Close();
            ResumeLayout();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("" + ex);
        }
    }
```

it was working but my problem is what if the user only update the number of epis and descrip and doesn't really intend to update the title,my method still detect that there's a duplicate since my logic was "if(ctr == 1)"..I think I'm missing some method or I'm in a wrong approach here..so I hope someone will enlighten me..sorry for being noob here Y.Y

Comment: In your database,  put a unique constraint on the "Title" column.  In your code, catch the constraint violation error and display a friendly error message to the user.

Comment: No problem being a noob...I still feel like a noob all the time!  :)  What I would do is start by going for a database solution first.  What you will want to do is make sure you have a primary key/identity, like RowID or something, and then you want to use a UNIQUE CONSTRAINT.  You can find how to use those here --> http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_unique.asp

Comment: @mbeckish unique constraint? in my database i saw Unique Index instead is that same ? and how do i catch an error? like try catch block?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your application supports multiple users you need to ensure changes are not made by another user between your check for duplicates and the database update.

The easiest way to do this is as mbeckish suggested, create a UNIQUE constraint on the title column:

```
ALTER TABLE maindatabase.animelist 
ADD CONSTRAINT U_animelist_TitleAnime UNIQUE (TitleAnime)
```

The database engine will then enforce unique titles and your client can handle user feedback by catching any constraint violation exception:

```
void checkData()
{
    SuspendLayout();
    try
    {

        updateData();

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MySqlException sqlEx = ex as MySqlExecption;
        // If there is a constraint violation error.
        // (I may have the wrong error number, please test.)
        if (sqlEx != null && sqlEx.Number == 1062) 
        {
            my = Form.ActiveForm as MyList;
            my.msg = new Message_Box();
            my.msg.Descrip.Text = "Record is already in the Database";
            my.msg.Title.Text = "Duplicate Record";
            my.msg.ShowDialog();
        } 
        else 
        {
            MessageBox.Show("" + ex);
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        ResumeLayout();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the correct answer right here.  Steve's code solution works but you are making extra work for yourself and the database.

Comment: Agreed but I think more importantly the other solution is not reliable. it is pretty hard to explain to a user that your application will prevent duplicate titles unless two users are changing things at once, if/when things go wrong. It also can be very hard to track down the source of a duplicate if it is not enforced by the database engine. Just want to stress the point as I've run into a number of these sorts of issues and they really annoy me :)

Comment: ohhh so there are other solutions here..ok gonna try this one out and check for the outcome..btw thanks for helping me guys ^^,

Comment: It works fine in updatating but my problem was the catch block when I intentionally update a duplicate record it doesn't catch the if statement and always returns to false(in the else braket)

Comment: I may have the error number wrong, what is sqlEx.Number equal to? Or is sqlEx null?

Comment: here some screen shots http://www.mediafire.com/view/0n967b2ublnj32k/help.png

or 

http://i61.tinypic.com/eulqty.png

Comment: Seems like i've solve it..just change the error num to 1062 and it works perfectly tnx for the code

Answer (score 2):

You don't want to have two Title with the same content. This could be achieved automatically with an UNIQUE index on that column. However, if you don't want to add an index for this then you could change your query to

```
SELECT ControlNum FROM maindatabase.animelist 
WHERE TitleAnime=?Title;
```

Then your logic should check also the ControlNum for differences

```
int currentNum = int.Parse(a.ToString()));
while (reader.Read())
{
    int ctrlNum = reader.GetInt32(0);
    if(ctrlNum != currentNum)
        ctr++;

}
if (ctr > 0)
    ......
```

In this way you increment your counter only if the ControlNum retrieved is different from the one you have selected in your interface

Another approach is the following (see comment below from @mbeckish)

```
SELECT 1 FROM maindatabase.animelist 
WHERE TitleAnime=?Title AND ControlNum <> ?CN

command.Parameters.AddWithValue("?CN", int.Parse(a.ToString()));
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("?Title", textBox3.Text);
object result = command.ExecuteScalar();
if(result != null)
{
    // Found a record with different ControlNum but with the same title
    // Error here
}
```

This is probably preferable to the first one because you don't need a loop and could use a simpler and more performant ExecuteScalar that returns only the first column of the first row (the 1 in this case) without building the MySqlDataReader object

Comment: thanks for the lessons..ahhhm what do i put inside the (ctr>0) the update method or the alert of duplication?

Comment: Well, the current code, the alert for duplication. The code above skips the increment of the control variable if the current record has the same ControlNum stored in the variable `a`, so, if after the Read loop the control variable is still zero then you don't have another Title like the original, otherwise there is already a record (with a different ControlNum) that has the Title typed by your user

Comment: ohh tnx so the else would be the update gonna try it out

Comment: Why not just add `ControlNum <> currentNum` to the SQL query?  That way, you could just select the record count, and get rid of the `while` loop.

Comment: If you cannot add the unique constraint to the database a safer way would be to do the update within a transaction, check for duplicates after the update, then rollback and raise an error if a duplicate was found.

Answer (score 0):

Change the duplicate finding SQL :

```
SELECT MAX(Title) as Count
FROM maindatabase.animelist
GROUP BY Title  , NumOfEpis, Description
```

if Count > 1 , then there is a duplicate.