# How to check if value already exists

Tags: c#, sql

I am trying to find a lot of time how to check if value exists and I can not find it, I need to check it twice:

> 1. in the sign up
> 2. in the log in

Here is my code block:

```
SqlConnection c = new SqlConnection(str);
        SqlCommand cmdUsername = new SqlCommand("SELECT 1 FROM Users WHERE UserName = @userName;", c);
        cmdUsername.Parameters.AddWithValue("userName", userName);
        cmdUsername.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
        SqlCommand cmdEmail = new SqlCommand("SELECT 1 FROM Users WHERE Email = @email;", c);
        cmdUsername.Parameters.AddWithValue("email", email);

        c.Open();
        nameExists = (int)cmdUsername.ExecuteScalar();
        emailExists = (int)cmdEmail.ExecuteScalar();
        c.Close();
```

When I am entering an email it marks the line

```
emailExists = (int)cmdEmail.ExecuteScalar();
```

And in the log in all is ok.

Please help me! Thank you all.

Comment: Here is the defenition:
`int nameExists, emailExists;`
The error is this:
**Object reference not set to an instance of an object.**

Comment: What is str? the connection string?

Comment: Yes, it is the connection string

Comment: Do you really have a record with the user name = @userName;?

Comment: I have a record with the name UserName, @userName is a variable

Comment: Where is the variable declared?

Comment: just before declaring the sqlconnection

Comment: Why don't you try with the string User Name instead of declaring a variable check if that works

Comment: As per your comment you want to prevent the data duplication right? so you have to set the column either as a primary key or a unique identifier

Comment: Can I set 3 primary keys? because I already have 1... I cant just check if it exists and require to enter again? Because I don`t want that there will 2 users with same username and password but with different privillages...

Comment: Yes you can do that but to get better result you have to set unique identifiers

Comment: on which column have you set the primary key? normally you have to set the primary key on email because email is unique names can be similar. Like there are million Alex, John etc names

Comment: My primary key is ID right now

Comment: @D4NieLDev set the primary key on email not ID and make your ID as identity column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to prevent duplicate User Name or Email you have to do the following.
1. Set the ID column as INT and set it to Identity column from column properties.
2. Set your Email or User Name as primary key to prevent either Email or User Name from duplication, The best practice is to make the Email column as primary key where there are a lot of cases that the users have same name but with unique emails.
[image: FYI]

Hope that helps!

**And to check whether username or email exist already here how you do it!**

```
SqlCommand check_User_Name = new SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [Table] WHERE ([user] = @user || [email] = @email)" , c);
check_User_Name.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", txtBox_UserName.Text);
check_User_Name.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", txtBox_Email.Text);
int UserExist = (int)check_User_Name.ExecuteScalar();

if(UserExist > 0)
{
   //Username exist
}
else
{
   //Username doesn't exist.
}
```

Comment: How can I print an error message when entering a value that already exists? For exemple a username john is already exists and now a new man wants to sign up with the name john, I want to print an error massage.

Comment: You need setup an error handler for that, you should ask a new question for that. for the moment if the answer helped you please accept it as an answer to help other people around.

Comment: I assume it will help but I prefer only 1 primary key

Comment: @D4NieLDev there you go, you have got only one primary key.

Comment: But I want to prevent either username and email duplication

Comment: @D4NieLDev Tell me which column you want to prevent from duplication? User Name or Email?

Comment: both email and username

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30082973/how-do-i-prevent-duplicate-records-in-my-database-while-updating-records) it is on your problem

Comment: So let me ask you one more thing, you have two textboxes for User name and Email and you have a button to submit user name and email to the database is that right?

Comment: Thanks!! it worked!! But fix your answer you should open the connection before the executescalar and close it after calling the executescalar

Answer (score 0):

Using your code, just optimized it a bit.

- Just one call to database
- Always close the connection even if a exception occurs
- Returns false when not found or na exception occurs, true otherwis

You can also add a check to the password if this is a login check.

```
public bool ValidData(string username, string email, string connectionString)
{
    var c = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    var cmdUsername = new SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Users WHERE UserName = @userName AND email = @email;", c);
    cmdUsername.Parameters.AddWithValue("userName", username);
    cmdUsername.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
    cmdUsername.Parameters.AddWithValue("email", email);

    c.Open();
    try
    {
        return (int) cmdUsername.ExecuteScalar() > 0;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //log exception

        return false;
    }
    finally
    {
        c.Close();
    }
}
```

If you just need the username or the email change:

```
    var cmdUsername = new SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Users WHERE UserName = @userName AND email = @email;", c);
```

to:

```
    var cmdUsername = new SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Users WHERE UserName = @userName OR email = @email;", c);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this -

```
string myConnection=str;//this is your connection string
string userName="";
string email="";
string parameteruserName = "";//your parameter should goes here
string parameterEmail = "";//your parameter should goes here
try
{
    SqlDataReader myReader = null;
    SqlCommand    myCommand = new SqlCommand(SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM  Users WHERE UserName =" +parameteruserName+" or  Email ="+parameterEmail 
   )  "+  ";", 
                                             myConnection);
    myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
    while(myReader.Read())
    {
      userName=  myReader["count"].ToString();

    }
myReader.close();
myConnection.Close();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
}


if(Convert.ToInt32(userName)>0){
//your user name is exists
}
```

Comment: I tries it, when I am entering an existing email I am getting no errors.
How can I know if the userName or email exists?

Comment: I cant call the myReader.close() method because it isn`t exists in current context.

Comment: If you will got nothing from the record, email or usert name  are empty string, so that mean the email or the user name is not exists.

Comment: I fixed the code, you can close the connection and reader inside the try clause.Let me know if that solve the problem (i don't have here visual studio).

Comment: Unfortunately, your solution didn`t work for me... Do you have anything else to suggest? Or if you can explain me why it works in the sign in screen but now in the sign up it will really estimated.

Comment: You want to check if there is already email or user like this? That is your problem?

Comment: He wants to prevent the duplicate usernames nothing relevant to it!

Comment: I have tried your new code, and if the userName or email are empty it says that they are not exists or user didn`t enter input? And my problem is what @the scion said

Comment: ok, I fixed the code, your query should be "IF ( "SELECT UserName ,Email 

FROM  Users WHERE UserName =" +parameteruserName+" or  Email ="+parameterEmail 
   ) > 0 
    SELECT  1
ELSE 
SELECT  0 "+  ";",

Comment: @thescion you could just change `SELECT UserName,Email` to `SELECT COUNT(*)` then u can avoid the IF.

Comment: prix I use what you said. D4NieLDev - the answer is yes, if you got record so that mean this user already exists

Comment: @thescion How should I know if the userName or email exists.**EDIT** If I am not entering nothing it tells me that the username and email entered are already exists (and they are nothing).

Comment: Maybe you have username and email with empty string? And it is looking for email=""?

Comment: How can I get to this situation?

Comment: You can add in the where clause where usernam is not null and email is not null

Comment: Now it shows username and email exists for any value

Comment: so there is problem with your query, I suggest you to open only managment studio sql server and to play with your query until you will got what you wand. Just declare parameter for username and email and try it directly in the sql server.